# How could I properly incorporate If statements into my Swift code?

Tags: swift, if-statement, swiftui

My question is quite general but still one which may help others in the community. I am coding a function in an app in which a user sets a weekly limit of how much they wish to spend every day, and the app totals their expenditure each day and tells them whether or not they exceeded their limit for the week. As you may be able to tell, this requires an If statement to determine what the app will tell the user depending on whether or not the totaled expenditure exceeded their limit. However, no matter where I put my If statement, there will always be one error or another, and I just don't understand how to include this If statement without error. All I'm asking is that someone checks my code and tells me how I can change the If statement or the code itself to allow them to co-exist. Thank you!

```
import SwiftUI

struct ProgressChart: View {
    @State private var WeekNumber = 1
    @State private var SetLimit = ""
    @State private var MondaySum = ""
    @State private var TuesdaySum = ""
    @State private var WednesdaySum = ""
    @State private var ThursdaySum = ""
    @State private var FridaySum = ""
    @State private var SaturdaySum = ""
    @State private var SundaySum = ""
    @State private var Result = ""
    

    var Total: Double {
        let MondaIsANumber = Double(MondaySum) ?? 0
        let TuesdayIsANumber = Double(TuesdaySum) ?? 0
        let WednesdayIsANumber = Double(WednesdaySum) ?? 0
        let ThursdayIsANumber = Double(ThursdaySum) ?? 0
        let FridayIsANumber = Double(FridaySum) ?? 0
        let SaturdayIsANumber = Double(SaturdaySum) ?? 0
        let SundayIsANumber = Double(SundaySum) ?? 0
        let SetLimitNumber = Double(SetLimit) ?? 0
        
    
        
        let amount = Double(MondaIsANumber + TuesdayIsANumber + WednesdayIsANumber + ThursdayIsANumber + FridayIsANumber + SaturdayIsANumber + SundayIsANumber) ?? 0
        
        if self.Total > SetLimitNumber {
            Result = "Unfortunately, you have surpassed your set limit this week."
        } else if self.Total < SetLimitNumber {
            Result = "Good job! You managed to stay under this week's limit!"
        }
        
        
        return amount
    }
    

    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            Text("Week:\(WeekNumber)")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                .padding(.top)
            
            Form {
                Section{
                    Text("What is my budget on products found online this week? ¥ \(SetLimit)" )
                        .bold()
                    TextField("¥", text: $SetLimit)
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                }
                
                Text("Daily sum of money spent on goods seen online")
                
                Section(header: Text("The Working Week")){
                    Text("Monday: \(MondaySum)" )
                    TextField("¥", text: $MondaySum)
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                    
                    Text("Tuesday: \(TuesdaySum)" )
                    TextField("¥", text: $TuesdaySum)
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                    
                    Text("Wednesday: \(WednesdaySum)" )
                    TextField("¥", text: $WednesdaySum)
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                    
                    Text("Thursday: \(ThursdaySum)" )
                    TextField("¥", text: $ThursdaySum)
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                    
                    Text("Friday: \(FridaySum)" )
                    TextField("¥", text: $FridaySum)
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                }
                    Section(header: Text("The Weekend")) {
                    Text("Saturday: \(SaturdaySum)" )
                    TextField("¥", text: $SaturdaySum)
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                    
                    Text("Sunday: \(SundaySum)" )
                    TextField("¥", text: $SundaySum)
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)

                
                    
                }
                Section {
                    Text("This Week's Total: $\(Total)")
                        .bold()
                        .font(.title)
                    Text("\(Result)")
                    
    

                    
                }
            }
        .navigationTitle("My Progress Chart")
    }
}

struct ProgressChart_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ProgressChart()
    }
    
}
}
```

Comment: Not an answer but I think you should consider moving logic into a separate type, like a class that conforms to ObservableObject, so your view is more focused on handling UI related things only. This will make your code more structured and easier to handle when each view/struct/class has clear and well defined responsibility instead of doing everything in one place. Read up on ObservableObject and @Published etc, they are very powerful tools that comes with SwiftUI

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of fixes we can apply.
First, self.Total references the property itself, which results in an infinite loop. It looks like you're trying to use amount here, so change this part to:

```
    if amount > SetLimitNumber {
        Result = "Unfortunately, you have surpassed your set limit this week."
    } else {
        Result = "Good job! You managed to stay under this week's limit!"
    }
```

Then, you'll notice when running the app and changing the Result value, you get a scary purple error. You're not supposed to modify Result during a view update. So instead of using a @State for Result, let the app determine the value of Result when appropriate.

```
    var Result: String {
        let SetLimitNumber = Double(SetLimit) ?? 0
        if Total > SetLimitNumber {
            return "Unfortunately, you have surpassed your set limit this week."
        } else {
            return "Good job! You managed to stay under this week's limit!"
        }
    }

    var Total: Double {
        let MondaIsANumber = Double(MondaySum) ?? 0
        let TuesdayIsANumber = Double(TuesdaySum) ?? 0
        let WednesdayIsANumber = Double(WednesdaySum) ?? 0
        let ThursdayIsANumber = Double(ThursdaySum) ?? 0
        let FridayIsANumber = Double(FridaySum) ?? 0
        let SaturdayIsANumber = Double(SaturdaySum) ?? 0
        let SundayIsANumber = Double(SundaySum) ?? 0

        return MondaIsANumber +
            TuesdayIsANumber +
            WednesdayIsANumber +
            ThursdayIsANumber +
            FridayIsANumber +
            SaturdayIsANumber +
            SundayIsANumber
    }
```

At this point, the app works just fine and there are no errors!
But we can do some code improvements! Note how in SwiftUI / iOS we prefer using "camelCase" over "PascalCase" for member variables, properties and functions.

A cleaner (and fixed) version of your code would look like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ProgressChart: View {
    @State private var weekNumber = 1
    @State private var setLimit = ""
    
    @State private var weekdays = [
        DaySum(day: .monday),
        DaySum(day: .tuesday),
        DaySum(day: .wednesday),
        DaySum(day: .thursday),
        DaySum(day: .friday)
    ]
    
    @State private var weekendDays = [
        DaySum(day: .saturday),
        DaySum(day: .sunday)
    ]
    
    var result: String {
        let limit = Double(setLimit) ?? 0
        if total > limit {
            return "Unfortunately, you have surpassed your set limit this week."
        } else {
            return "Good job! You managed to stay under this week's limit!"
        }
    }
    
    var total: Double {
        (weekdays + weekendDays).map { daySum in daySum.amount }.reduce(0, +)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Week:\(weekNumber)")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                .padding(.top)
            
            Form {
                Section {
                    Text("What is my budget on products found online this week? ¥ \(setLimit)" )
                        .bold()
                    TextField("¥", text: $setLimit)
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                }
                
                Text("Daily sum of money spent on goods seen online")
                
                Section(header: Text("The Working Week")){
                    ForEach(weekdays.indices) { i in
                        Text(weekdays[i].display)
                        TextField("¥", text: $weekdays[i].sum)
                            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                    }
                }
                
                Section(header: Text("The Weekend")) {
                    ForEach(weekendDays.indices) { i in
                        Text(weekendDays[i].display)
                        TextField("¥", text: $weekendDays[i].sum)
                            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                    }
                }
                
                Section {
                    Text("This Week's Total: $\(total)")
                        .bold()
                        .font(.title)
                    
                    Text(result)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("My Progress Chart")
        }
    }
}

struct ProgressChart_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ProgressChart()
    }
}

struct DaySum {
    let day: Day
    var sum: String = ""
    
    var amount: Double {
        Double(sum) ?? 0
    }
    
    var display: String {
        "\(day.rawValue.capitalized): \(sum)"
    }
}

enum Day: String {
    case monday
    case tuesday
    case wednesday
    case thursday
    case friday
    case saturday
    case sunday
}
```

The code above will do exactly the same as yours!
Of course, you should put different structs and enums in their own files.
There's still much more we can do, but I wanted to inspire you with at least this much!

Answer (score 1):

the computed property Total is calling it self and in the Total property Result var is been updated but Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior .

```
  struct ProgressChart: View {
 @State private var WeekNumber = 1
 @State private var SetLimit = ""
 @State private var MondaySum = ""
 @State private var TuesdaySum = ""
 @State private var WednesdaySum = ""
 @State private var ThursdaySum = ""
 @State private var FridaySum = ""
 @State private var SaturdaySum = ""
 @State private var SundaySum = ""
 @State private var Result = ""
 
 var Total: Double {
     let MondaIsANumber = Double(MondaySum) ?? 0
     let TuesdayIsANumber = Double(TuesdaySum) ?? 0
     let WednesdayIsANumber = Double(WednesdaySum) ?? 0
     let ThursdayIsANumber = Double(ThursdaySum) ?? 0
     let FridayIsANumber = Double(FridaySum) ?? 0
     let SaturdayIsANumber = Double(SaturdaySum) ?? 0
     let SundayIsANumber = Double(SundaySum) ?? 0
    let amount = Double(MondaIsANumber + TuesdayIsANumber + WednesdayIsANumber + ThursdayIsANumber + FridayIsANumber + SaturdayIsANumber + SundayIsANumber) 
     return amount
 }
 

 
 var body: some View {
     VStack {

         Text("Week:\(WeekNumber)")
             .font(.largeTitle)
             .fontWeight(.bold)
             .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
             .padding(.top)
         
         Form {
             Section{
                 Text("What is my budget on products found online this week? ¥ \(SetLimit)" )
                     .bold()
                 TextField("¥", text: $SetLimit)
                     .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
             }
             
             Text("Daily sum of money spent on goods seen online")
             
             Section(header: Text("The Working Week")){
                 Text("Monday: \(MondaySum)" )
                 TextField("¥", text: $MondaySum)
                     .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                 
                 Text("Tuesday: \(TuesdaySum)" )
                 TextField("¥", text: $TuesdaySum)
                     .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                 
                 Text("Wednesday: \(WednesdaySum)" )
                 TextField("¥", text: $WednesdaySum)
                     .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                 
                 Text("Thursday: \(ThursdaySum)" )
                 TextField("¥", text: $ThursdaySum)
                     .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                 
                 Text("Friday: \(FridaySum)" )
                 TextField("¥", text: $FridaySum)
                     .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
             }
                 Section(header: Text("The Weekend")) {
                 Text("Saturday: \(SaturdaySum)" )
                 TextField("¥", text: $SaturdaySum)
                     .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                 
                 Text("Sunday: \(SundaySum)" )
                 TextField("¥", text: $SundaySum)
                     .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                 
             }
             Section {
                let total = Total
                 Text("This Week's Total: $\(total)")
                     .bold()
                     .font(.title)
                if total > (Double(SetLimit) ?? 0) {
                    Text("Unfortunately, you have surpassed your set limit this week.")
                 } else {
                    Text("Good job! You managed to stay under this week's limit!")
                 }
             }
         }
     .navigationTitle("My Progress Chart")
 }
 }

   struct ProgressChart_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
     ProgressChart()
      }
 
   }
  }
```